# How do we return the ID of the column that corresponds to the field having repeating values in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have a table A (just an example), which has fields `ID`, `Type`.  I want to know how to return the `ID` of the field that has repeating type values, i.e.

```
id | Type
-------------
2  | Me
3  | Me
4  | You
```

I want the values 2 and 3 returned as ID.  How do I approach this?

What I initially did was this:

```
SELECT Name FROM A GROUP BY Name HAVING COUNT(NAME) > 1
```

But this only returns the value `Me`.  I want to know how to return:

```
Id | Type
2  | Me
3  | Me
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filter your table by using a subquery in the `WHERE` clause which finds names occurring two or more times:

```
SELECT Id, Type
FROM table 
WHERE name in (SELECT Name FROM A GROUP BY Name HAVING COUNT(NAME) > 1);
```

Comment: Yes this is possible..But i want it to be generic.

Comment: Wherein I don't actually know what the ID is and I want the ID ti be returned so as to be used on a join condition

Comment: I have used your query as a subquery to return results, check updated answer

Answer (score 2):

You may use `COUNT` as an analytic function:

```
SELECT id, type
FROM
(
    SELECT id, type, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY type) cnt
    FROM yourTable
) t
WHERE cnt > 1;
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm just a begginer and don't know how to use this concept!

Comment: @AshweshAnand The answer I gave is probably the most efficient way to solve your problem.  But if you don't know analytic functions, then using another approach is OK too.

Answer (score 2):

Hello maybe you just need to do it like this :

```
SELECT ID,NAME FROM A WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM A GROUP BY Name HAVING COUNT(NAME)>1 )
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SELECT a.* FROM example a
JOIN (SELECT type FROM example GROUP BY Type HAVING COUNT(type)>1)
b on a.type = b.type
```